# Bigger iOS keyboard with bigger keys

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

I wanted to know if there is an option to display a bigger keyboard with a bigger font of keys? Can I control the size of the keys?

Comment: Did you ever see something like this? Can you provide screenshots? Because basically something like this is not standard conform.

Comment: Gogge it for "ios custom keyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot.  This is standard Apple stuff.  You can create your own keyboard from scratch.  But It sounds like you are asking if this is just a simple settings thing which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way you can control the size of the keys of the keyboard.

You would need to customise your own keyboard by creating your own buttons.